# Shared pixels on shared edges

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, pixel

[image]

I am trying to determine how to return coordinates of shared pixels from shared edges in an image (example image above). Essentially, three things would be returned.

1. An image that draws over the shared edges in red (or another colour,
   it doesn't matter.
2. A dataframe that lists the shared pixel coordinates.
3. What I call a complexity index, which essentially lists which
   polygon has the most shared edges. So, using the image provided,
   polygon 1 has one shared edge, polygons 2 and 3 have three shared
   edges, polygon 4 has two shared edges, and polygon 5 has one shared
   edge.

I've had no real luck with this. Below is some code that I've attempted. I've started by doing contour selection and creating a nested dictionary (`contour_df`) with image contour data (`contour_df`) that lists all the pixel information from my image. A big problem I'm running into off the bat is that `itertools.permutations` is running every pixel coordinate combination, which takes forever, and I can't get past it to try anything else.

Ultimately, I believe I'm approaching this problem incorrectly and may need to start from scratch. Thanks for any and all suggestions.

```
def complexity_estimator(contour_df):

    adjacency_list = []
    for i in range(0, contour_df.shape[0]):
        if contour_df.iloc[i]["parent_index"] == -1:
            adjacency_list.append(0)
        else:
            # list coordinates for the contour we are interested In
            contour_coordinate = contour_df.iloc[i]["contour"]

            # list of coordinates of each of the siblings that we are interested In (list of listS)
            contour_coordinate_siblings = contour_df[contour_df["parent_index"] == contour_df.iloc[i]["parent_index"]]['contour'].values

            count = 0
            for sibling_contour in contour_coordinate_siblings:

                # compare contour_coordinate with sibling_contour
                adjacent = complexity_measure(contour_coordinate,sibling_contour)

                if adjacent == True:
                    count = count + 1

            adjacency_list.append(count)

    contour_df['complexity'] = adjacency_list

    return contour_df


def complexity_measure(contour_coordinates1, contour_coordinates2):

    if np.array_equal(contour_coordinates1, contour_coordinates2):
        return False
    else:
        new_pairs =  [list(zip(x,contour_coordinates2)) for x in itertools.permutations(contour_coordinates2,len(contour_coordinates2))]

        print (new_pairs)
        #dist = math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
    return True
```

Comment: yes, you're approaching this wrong. never ever throw around lists of pixels (at least not huge lists...) approach: get a mask for the hexagons first (white inner parts). then isolate each (I'd recommend connected component labeling) and dilate it. sum them all. you'll get a map that says for each pixel how many hexagons are nearby. if you now select those overlap regions, then dilate, then sample the labels map for every pixel in each overlap region, you can get the set of hexagons that are adjacent to that edge (overlap region)

Comment: pandas is also the wrong tool here. what you're doing with it also strikes me as questionable. this is 2d raster data (images), not tabular data.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Christoph, once again you've offered great advice. I'm familiar with connected components and dilations, and that was my initial attemp. I didn't approach it from masking the white parts first. I can do this easily enough, so thank you for the reassurance. Can you clarify what you mean by 'sum them all' and 'select those overlap regions, then dilate, then sample the labels map' ? Thanks again!

Comment: a mask, containing 0 and 1 (if it contains 255, better change that). add multiple masks (elementwise, the straightforward way), you get the 0s and 1s summing up to however many of those masks in that position were true.

Comment: Cool, that helps a lot. Thanks @ChristophRackwitz

Comment: Your description is missing important information: is the geometry only known by this image, or is there a representation in the form of segments or polygons ?

Comment: Notice that it will not be possible to find the common edges by purely local processing, because you need to know which (parts of)  edges are bordering an hexagon. (You don't want to take into account the triangle between 2-3-4.)

Comment: Also unclear in what form you want the result. A list of pixels does not seem appropriate (notice that the image is antialiased, so that not all pixels are taking "in full".)